# What method would be best to build this complex graph

Tags: php, javascript, css, user-interface, charts

After 15 years doing UI development, there's very little I look at and think, "how on earth do I do that."  This is one of those times.

A graphic designer has sold my clients on a very complex graph in the shape of a pentagon, made up of 5 individual triangles.  The designer has specified that each triangle should be a specific color to match the branding, and each should "fill" based on the percentage of the process that each color represents.  You almost have to see the image to understand:
[image]

I've been racking my brain for a day trying to figure out how to accomplish this task.  The client has specified that it must be compatible in all major browsers, which I'm going to tell him will be IE7+ for sanity's sake.  That heavily limits CSS3 techniques, though I'd certainly entertain CSS3 methods for lack of other ideas.  I'd prefer not to be up late nights beating on Action Script, so Flash is at the very bottom of my wish list.  I've actually brainstormed how to do it using Sprites, but the idea of producing 250 or 500 triangles and the associated CSS ranks right up there with trading Chrome for IE6.

The site is built on PHP/MySQL, and we heavily use Jquery.  We have a full version of FusionCharts and HighCharts at our disposal as well if necessary.  If there's a commercial product out there that can achieve this, I'm certainly willing to purchase it to make this work.

What is the best method to achieve this difficult task?

Comment: +1 for a well-written question discussing many possible alternatives for a topic that could easily (and wrongly) have been a "gimme-codez" question.  Thanks for that.

Comment: Lol, couldn't the designer have the customer settle with a pie chart? :D

Comment: Trust me, I tried.  If I hadn't been a graphic designer before I saw the light, someone might have gotten hurt....

Comment: Looks like the IBM branding colours... just sayin'

Comment: @bpeterson76: I've updated my answer to include code. It took me almost an hour, so I hope it's useful.

Comment: @thirtydot:  Wow!  Awesome work...definitely useful stuff.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Unless I could find an implementation *already written*, I'd use [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/).

It will take significant work, but the end result should be very good.

Take a look at some of the demos, they're incredibly slick.

> Raphaël currently supports Firefox
>   3.0+, Safari 3.0+, Chrome 5.0+, Opera 9.5+ and Internet Explorer 6.0+.

---

This seemed interesting, so I decided to implement it myself with Raphaël:

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/2Tsjy/

It should work in "all browsers". The only part I didn't do was the text.

[image]

**JavaScript:**

```
var paper = Raphael("pentagon"),
    fullNum = [40, 53],
    borderColours = ['#329342','#9e202c','#f47933','#811f5a','#11496c'],
    fillColours = ['#74ae3d','#d01f27','#eaa337','#32133f','#2c7aa1'],
    triangles = [],
    border, fill, st, i;

for (i=0; i<5; i++) {
    border = paper.path(getPercentPath(0)).attr({
        'fill': borderColours[i],
        'stroke-width': 0        
    }),
    fill = paper.path(["M", 116, 123] + "l-44,61 88,0z").attr({
        'stroke': fillColours[i],
        'stroke-width': 6
    });
    triangles.push(border);

    st = paper.set();
    st.push(border, fill);
    st.rotate(i * 72, 116, 113);

    setPercent(i, 30+Math.floor(Math.random()*70));
}

function getPercentPath(percent) {
    var ratio = percent/100;
    return ["M", 116, 128] + "l-" + ratio*fullNum[0] + "," + ratio*fullNum[1] + " " + ratio*fullNum[0]*2 + ",0z";
}
function setPercent(i, percent) {
    triangles[i].attr({
        path: getPercentPath(percent)
    });
}


setInterval(function(){
    for (var i=0; i<5; i++) {
        setPercent(i, 30+Math.floor(Math.random()*70));
    }
}, 2000);
```

**CSS:**

```
#pentagon {
    width: 226px;
    height: 227px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    background: #fff;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8)
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="pentagon"></div>
```

Answer (score 7):

I'd have to recommend RaphaelJS (see http://raphaeljs.com/). It is IE7 compatible, and you can do the triangles just fine: you need to do the math, but quite possible.

EDIT: look at http://www.chittram.com/editor.jsp for a quick sample of some of the shapes that can be done. That site is an interactive editor but the core capabilities you need are demonstrated.

Answer (score 7):

What about `<canvas>`?
You can easily draw one triangle and then draw the others by just rotating the canvas `360/5` degrees.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Stijntjhe/dC6kX/

```
window.onload = function() {
    var ce = document.getElementById('ce');
    var c = ce.getContext('2d');
    c.translate(ce.offsetWidth / 2, ce.offsetHeight / 2);

    for(var pie = 0; pie < 5; pie++) {
        c.save();
        c.rotate(pie/5 * Math.PI * 2);

        c.beginPath();
        c.moveTo(0, -10);
        c.lineTo(-50, -80);
        c.lineTo(50, -80);
        c.lineTo(0, -10);
        c.lineWidth = 5;
        c.lineCap = 'square';
        c.strokeStyle = colors[pie];
        c.stroke();

        c.restore();
    } 
}
```

Becomes:

[image]

Cons:
Maybe not cross-browser yet.

Comment: +1 For a great fiddle. I haven't had very long to play around with it at all but just as a quick and dirty (and somewhat inaccurate) proof of concept I've forked Stijntjhe's fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kXFQe/. The percentages need to be calculate to reflect within the triangle but just thought I'd show it's possible with canvas.

Comment: It still needs some math, I just guessed the cords now.

Comment: @Ben Stephenson: I guess the stated `not cross-browser yet`.

Comment: If its your intention to post comments on every helpful answer on stackoverflow quoting part of the answer then best of luck

Answer (score 4):

If it absolutely must be as compatible as possible, I would generate an SVG image and render it to PNG. This is not nearly as slow as it sounds for an image like this with so few points.

Here's a very quick, very dirty example. It assumes that you have the [ImageMagick](http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) extension available though in a pinch you could dump the SVG to a file and `exec()` a command-line tool like [rsvg](http://librsvg.sourceforge.net/). Obviously the "right" answer involves some sort of caching scheme for the rendered graph. Also, forgive me for not being more of a SVG ninja.

**graph.svg.php:**

```
<?php echo '<'; ?>?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg width="240" height="240"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">

  <g transform="translate(120,120) translate(0,15)">
    <polygon fill="none" stroke="green" stroke-width="10" 
              points="0,0 -50,68.82 50,68.82" />
    <g transform="scale(<?php echo $fill['green']; ?>)">
      <polygon fill="green" stroke="green" stroke-width="10" 
                points="0,0 -50,68.82 50,68.82" />
    </g>
  </g>

  <g transform="translate(120,120) rotate(72) translate(0,15)">
    <polygon fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="10" 
              points="0,0 -50,68.82 50,68.82" />
    <g transform="scale(<?php echo $fill['red']; ?>)">
      <polygon fill="red" stroke="red" stroke-width="10" 
                points="0,0 -50,68.82 50,68.82" />
    </g>
  </g>

  <g transform="translate(120,120) rotate(144) translate(0,15)">
    <polygon fill="none" stroke="yellow" stroke-width="10" 
              points="0,0 -50,68.82 50,68.82" />
    <g transform="scale(<?php echo $fill['yellow']; ?>)">
      <polygon fill="yellow" stroke="yellow" stroke-width="10" 
                points="0,0 -50,68.82 50,68.82" />
    </g>
  </g>

  <g transform="translate(120,120) rotate(216) translate(0,15)">
    <polygon fill="none" stroke="purple" stroke-width="10" 
              points="0,0 -50,68.82 50,68.82" />
    <g transform="scale(<?php echo $fill['purple']; ?>)">
      <polygon fill="purple" stroke="purple" stroke-width="10" 
                points="0,0 -50,68.82 50,68.82" />
    </g>
  </g>

  <g transform="translate(120,120) rotate(288) translate(0,15)">
    <polygon fill="none" stroke="blue" stroke-width="10" 
              points="0,0 -50,68.82 50,68.82" />
    <g transform="scale(<?php echo $fill['blue']; ?>)">
      <polygon fill="blue" stroke="blue" stroke-width="10" 
                points="0,0 -50,68.82 50,68.82" />
    </g>
  </g>

</svg>
```

**render.php:**

```
<?php

$fill = array(
    'green'  => 0.5,
    'red'    => 0.8,
    'yellow' => 0.55,
    'purple' => 0.4,
    'blue'   => 0.75,
);

ob_start();
include('graph.svg.php');
$svg = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

$im = new Imagick();
$im->readImageBlob($svg);
$im->setImageFormat('png24');
$png = $im->getImagesBlob();
$im->clear();
$im->destroy();

header('Content-Type: image/png');
header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($png));
echo $png;
exit;
```

Output looks like this:

[image: Rendered graph]

Answer (score 2):

I think if you have to do it in JS/CSS and Flash/HTML5 isn't an option, take a look at a handy trick of using triangles in CSS:

http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/css/slopes

And an alternative reference:

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/

By setting the border thickness's of boxes cleverly, you can get any shape triangle you want, at any rotation.  It's tricky to figure out, and I don't have code handy but it is possible.

You could nest triangles within each other (looking the sample picture I note it is composed entirely of triangles, the inner triangle is an inverted nest of the outer triangle) so I think it's perfectly possible, although that maths might get a bit tricky in regards to positioning and if you need the chart to be flexible (arbitrary numbers of triangles and sizes).

Comment: This is a worthy option, but one that I would only use if I was trying to avoid JavaScript, and keep it to pure HTML/CSS (plus a server side language to do the border math). Once you have to use JavaScript, you might as well just use a library such as Raphaël.

Comment: Another way of making triangles is to use a linear css gradient (not sure of browser support, though): http://jlongster.com/s/dom3d/