# Polygon graph in html

Tags: html, css, graph, svg, polygon

I'am looking for a good library to make polygon graph like this in html / javascript / css / svg.

Example

[image: here]

If you have any.

Regards

Bussiere

Comment: What libraries have you looked up so far and turned down?

Comment: See this:

http://www.farinspace.com/top-svg-javascript-libraries-worth-looking-at/

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/) is a good choice if you want to implement this yourself.

Note that there's already a [charting library](http://g.raphaeljs.com/) for Raphaël, which may help.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6153453/what-method-would-be-best-to-build-this-complex-graph/6153501#6153501) uses Raphaël to make a similar chart.

Another choice is [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/polar-spider), here's a not very similar [example](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/polar-spider). You'd have to make the chart type yourself, if it doesn't already exist.